# Does the word “each” have the present or past meaning?

Tags: exam-questions, error

I have to choose a mistake in the sentence

> "The path **was made** by the walkers **which** **crossed** the mountain **each**
>   summer".

Which letter is not standard English, and why?

> A. was made
>
> B. which
>
> C.crossed
>
> D. each

Comment: The non-standard *word* (not *letter*) in your context is ***which***, which should be ***who*** (or feasibly ***that***). The word ***each*** has no implications as regards past, present, or future summers - we only know the sentence is talking about *past* summers because of the past tense verb forms ***was made*** and ***crossed***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - By "letter", I'm pretty sure the OP meant A, B, C, or D (in this case, B).

Comment: @J.R.♦: Very likely. But at the very least it's unusual / distracting phrasing that native speakers wouldn't be likely to use in this context. So I think if it passed unremarked, that might well be misleading for some of the target audience here.

Answer (score 4):

Only verbs have tense so your question about past and present meanings of **each** makes no sense because it is not a verb.

The answer wanted is to replace **which** by **who** because **who** refers to people whereas **which** does not.